# Why my first network call failed

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm requesting simple list of data from my server. I am using retrofit and I have set Stetho as Network Interceptor to monitor network calls.

[image]

As You can see in this screen shot from chrome inspect window. every network call I made after initial network call get failed and automatically calling the server for the second time and that gets success. Here's the code for the network call.

**Function for network call**

```
public void getLocalAreasFromServer(int districtId) {

        APIService service = ServiceGenerator.createService(APIService.class, this);
        citiesListCall = service.getCitiesList(districtId);
        citiesListCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<CityItem>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<CityItem>> call, Response<List<CityItem>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    ArrayAdapter<CityItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(InsertAndUpdateAddressActivity.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, response.body());
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    localAreaSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

                    if(hasExtra){
                        AddressTable address = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("selected_address");

                        for(CityItem cityObj: response.body()){
                            if(cityObj.getCity_name().equals(address.getLocalArea())){
                                localAreaSpinner.setSelection(adapter.getPosition(cityObj));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<CityItem>> call, Throwable t) {
                t.getStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
```

**API Service Interface**

```
public interface APIService {

    @GET("get_cities_list")
    Call<List<CityItem>> getCitiesList(@Query("district_id") int district_id);

}
```

**`ServiceGenerator` Class**

```
public class ServiceGenerator {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://www.baseURL.com/mobile/";

    private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient =
            new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addNetworkInterceptor(new StethoInterceptor())
                    .connectTimeout(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request original = chain.request();

                    Request request = original.newBuilder()
                            .header("Authorization", "Basic cmdkZXY6cmcxMjM=")
                            .method(original.method(), original.body())
                            .build();

                    return chain.proceed(request);
                }
            });

    private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create()))
                    .client(httpClient.build());

    private static Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, Context context) {
        Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(context);
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

I tried to debug but is't never comes to `onFailure` method. But I can see bellow message in Logcat but It's not printing from `onFailure`.

```
java.io.IOException: Address already in use
at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.bindLocal(Native Method)
at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.bind(LocalSocketImpl.java:306)
at android.net.LocalServerSocket.<init>(LocalServerSocket.java:48)
at com.facebook.stetho.server.LocalSocketServer.bindToSocket(LocalSocketServer.java:142)
at com.facebook.stetho.server.LocalSocketServer.listenOnAddress(LocalSocketServer.java:78)
at com.facebook.stetho.server.LocalSocketServer.run(LocalSocketServer.java:74)
at com.facebook.stetho.server.ServerManager$1.run(ServerManager.java:40)
```

My application is working fine and user does not notice this. But I need to know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was reported on Github [here](https://github.com/facebook/stetho/issues/36).

The solution suggested there is to add Stetho to your Proguard rules:

```
-keep class com.facebook.stetho.**{ *; }
```